# How to combine different cases

Tags: sql, hana

I have a a lot of projects that are listed in tables and have different phases and different tasks in those phases. Each row has a percentage that is like 100/max(rowID). (E.g. 20 rows equals 5% per row)
One column has just two possibilities of entered Data: "Yes" or "No"
If all rows are selected with "yes" the percentage of the whole project is at 100%

My Current code sums up all percentages of each row that is selected with "yes" by phases.
My question is: Is it possibly to have another column, that gives the total percentage of all rows by the phase, so that I have the outcome of how many rows have a "yes" out of how many rows grouped by each phase?

```
SELECT T2."Name", MIN(T1."START"), T1."CLOSE" AS "Predicted Closing",
       MAX(T1."FINISHDATE"), SUM(T1."PERCENT"),
       DAYS_BETWEEN(T1."CLOSE", MAX(T1."FINISHDATE")) AS "Overdue"
FROM OPMG T0 
INNER JOIN PMG1 T1 ON T0."AbsEntry" = T1."AbsEntry"
INNER JOIN PMC2 T2 ON T1."StageID" = T2."StageID"
WHERE T1."FINISH" = 'Y'
  AND T0."DocNum" = '[%DocNum]'
  AND T2."Name" NOT LIKE 'Client:%'
GROUP BY T2."Name", T1."CLOSE", T1."StageID"
ORDER BY T1."StageID"
```

I appreciate any help or hint!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What happens if you remove T1."StageID" from the GROUP BY clause?

Comment: 1). General error;277 not a GROUP BY expression: 'T1.StageID' must be in group by clause.: line 17 col 1  'Benutzerdefinierte Werte' (CSHS) (at pos 420)

Comment: Oops. the ORDER BY references that column. Still a bit odd grouping by a column not in the select list.

Comment: You´re right, but in this case at the end I don´t need the stage ID as an output, just as an ordering-mechanism (T2."Name" is not in the same order as T1."StageID". Anyhow as I have selected as WHERE T1."FINISH" = 'Y' but need both outputs ( 'N' as well) , therefor the outputs (N+Y) and only Y I need help in this case...

Comment: Remove StageID from the GROUP BY. ORDER BY MAX(StageID), or MIN().

Comment: One of the conditions was that the percentage was grouped by StageID or Stage Name... But thank you for the input!

Answer (score 0):

It was better to enter part of your data and your desired output. However, to calculate the percentage of rows that are grouped and a column has a yes value for them, you can do the following.

```
sum(case when column = "yes" then 1 end) * 100 /count(Name) as percentage
```

Comment: I was not aware that the possibility of when-clauses exists! Thank you! I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `avg()`:

```
avg(case when column = 'yes' then 100.0 else 0 end) as percentage
```

Comment: I was not aware that the possibility of when-clauses exists! avg would lead in that case to the requested outcome. I used instead the above mentioned method with sum.
Thank you for that inspiration, Gordon!